# lcdf-typetools conflicts with openmpi in Gentoo

Tags: dependencies, gentoo

here is the output after running **nice -n 15 emerge -abvuDN --quiet-build=y --autounmask-write --ignore-built-slot-operator-deps=y --backtrack=50 world**

```
 * Error: The above package list contains packages which cannot be 
 * installed at the same time on the same system. 

  (app-text/lcdf-typetools-2.100::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by 
    >=app-text/lcdf-typetools-2.92[kpathsea] required by (app-text/texlive-2012::gentoo, installed) 

  (sys-cluster/openmpi-1.4.3::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by 
    sys-cluster/openmpi[cxx?,fortran?,romio?,threads?] (sys-cluster/openmpi[cxx,fortran,romio]) require 
    sys-cluster/openmpi[cxx] required by (dev-libs/boost-1.55.0-r1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
```

Then I have masked lcdf-typetools and ran the same update command, it shows.

```
* Error: The above package list contains packages which cannot be 
 * installed at the same time on the same system. 

  (sys-cluster/openmpi-1.4.3::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by 
    sys-cluster/openmpi[cxx?,fortran?,romio?,threads?] (sys-cluster/openmpi[cxx,fortran,romio]) required by (virtual/mpi-2.0-r3::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) 
    sys-cluster/openmpi[cxx] required by (dev-libs/boost-1.55.0-r1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) 

  (app-text/lcdf-typetools-2.104::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by 
    >=app-text/lcdf-typetools-2.92[kpathsea] required by (app-text/texlive-2012::gentoo, installed) 


For more information about Blocked Packages, please refer to the following 
section of the Gentoo Linux x86 Handbook (architecture is irrelevant): 

http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?full=1#blocked 


The following mask changes are necessary to proceed: 
 (see "package.unmask" in the portage(5) man page for more details) 
# required by app-text/texlive-2012 
# required by @selected 
# required by @world (argument) 
# /etc/portage/package.mask/a: 
#=sci-mathematics/petsc-3.5.1 
#=app-text/poppler-0.24.5 
#=app-text/poppler-0.24.5 
#net-libs/webkit-gtk 
#<=x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers-340.46 
=app-text/lcdf-typetools-2.104 

NOTE: The --autounmask-keep-masks option will prevent emerge 
      from creating package.unmask or ** keyword changes.
```

how can I sort out this conflict? It has been there for many days.

**updates:**

I have tried to unmerge both atoms that requires openmpi, but it is still been pulled over by other atoms.

**notes**

openmpi is very important for me, there is no compromise for not installing it. 
lcdf-typetools is pulled over by texlive-2012, which is also one of the key packages I use reguarly

Comment: It sounds like the two packages cannot be installed at the same time. Any luck emerging the dependencies on there own.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMercier, can you please give an example how to emerging dependencies individually?

Comment: I forgot to check back. I added my answer a while ago. Did this help?

Answer (score 0):

You should emerge one of the packages that cannot be installed at the same time.

```
emerge app-text/lcdf-typetools
```

or

```
emerge sys-cluster/openmpi
```

Then try updating your whole system.